# Slow MySQL Performance when using >= and % in Varchar columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query for BETWEEN date, but the problem is that the column is in VARCHAR with date for "yyyymmddhhmmss". The performance is sluggish and I have no idea on what I can do to optimize it. Would be great if somebody can point out to me on the next step to do.

Here's the code:

```
SELECT `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `date_added` 
FROM `table` 
where date_added >= '201306%' 
AND date_added <= '201309%'
```

Comment: you could start by ditching varchars and using a proper date/datetime field type instead.

Comment: What do you expect when using strings for dates?

Comment: the both above me are right ;) but nevertheless do you have an index set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should use a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column instead of `VARCHAR`.

Regardless of data type, you can improve the performance by adding an index to that column:

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
  ADD INDEX date_added (date_added);
```

In terms of the syntax of your query, you should not be using the `%` wildcard unless you are using `LIKE` in your query. For example, to get all dates in June through September:

```
SELECT `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `date_added` 
FROM `table` 
where date_added >= '201306' 
AND date_added < '201310'
```

You may also want to consider padding those values with trailing zeroes so they match the yyyymmddhhmmss format.

For example:

```
SELECT `id`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `date_added` 
FROM `table` 
where date_added >= '20130600000000' 
AND date_added < '20131000000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `date_added` to `datetime` field and all your woes will go away.

You will need to do it in two steps with an `UPDATE` SQL statement into a new field and then rename the field from `date_added_nonstring` to `date_added`.

Comment: Since those are datetime values, `DATE` is not an appropriate data type. The proper choices would be `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`. Also, although those data types are obviously better design choices, without an index the query will be just as slow with those types as it is with `VARCHAR`, so changing the data type will not address the slow performance.

Comment: You are right, I mis-read, he mentioned date_added, anyway, datetime is the right one, timestamp is a bit more difficult to "read" when you do simple queries.